# customErrors not redirecting

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using this and it works fine as long as it matches up with the user in ADGroup.  However, it gave a generic server page when there is no user in ADGroup.  Can someone help me with this as why CustomErrors is not working and what did i do wrong? I googled and found that i didn't do anything different to what people suggested however it is still not directing me to the page i wanted.  I appreciate any help and thank you.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" ></authentication>
<identity impersonate="false" />
<authorization>
  <allow roles="TUL.Testing,DACOnlineDrugAlcohol"/>
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
</customErrors>
```

Comment: If you deny permissions to a folder, you can then attempt to redirect to another page in that same folder.

Comment: That should be "you CAN'T then attempt to redirect to another page in that same folder"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your `<configuration>` node:

below is an example, add the relevant pages as needed

```
 <configuration>
.
.
.

 <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/> 
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="Error404.aspx" responseMode="File"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="Error500.aspx" responseMode="File"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
.
.
.
</configuration>
```

Comment: it's still not working.  still giving the generic page.